# Django: "How often" do I need @transaction.atomic

Tags: python, django

> atomic blocks can be nested. In this case, when an inner block
>   completes successfully, its effects can still be rolled back if an
>   exception is raised in the outer block at a later point.

Do I understand correctly that I don't need to add `@transaction.atomic` decorator before `do_stuff()`? If do_staff changes the database and an exception occurs, the parent `view_func` will take care of the rollback.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
```

That's **not** neccesary, correct?

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def do_stuff():
    do_something_in_the_database()

@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote you used says that a rollback will occur if `viewfunc` raises an exception, no matter the success of the nested atomic in `do_stuff`.
But yes, you are right with your assumption that the atomic on `viewfunc` will take care of the rollback if `do_stuff` or `viewfunc` raises an exception.

I would still decorate `do_stuff` so that you can you handle exceptions raised by it in `viewfunc` while also rolling back the transaction. 
If you only decorate `viewfunc` the error may propagate and end up showing the user a 500-error view.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  The way you showed the code - no you don't need `@transaction.atomic` on `do_stuff`.

However, if you want `do_stuff` to be able to fail independently of `viewfunc` you might.

For example:

```
@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except Exception:
        handle_exception()
    do_other_stuff
```

In this case, failure in `do_stuff` will rollback that segment but not cancel the outer transaction.

You can see more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/